# Referencing properties within an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a Grid object using the following code:

```
var Grid = {
    rows: 5,
    cols: 6,
    getDimensions: function() {
        console.log(rows + ' by ' + cols);
    }(),
};
```

My `getDimensions` function isn't working however because it cannot reference the `rows` and `cols` properties that I previously set. `this` is set to the window so I'm not sure how I would reference these properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var Grid = {
    rows: 5,
    cols: 6,
    getDimensions: function() {
        console.log(this.rows + ' by ' + this.cols);
    }(),
};
```

Use `this` to reference other properties of the object. Keep scope in mind.
Alternatively you can use `Grid.rows` and `Grid.cols`